# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module toastr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js, bower

I am working on a SailsJS web app, using Angular. However, I am running into issues. When I load my page, nothing appears and the copnsole is full of errors, most elating to angular.js

> ncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module HomepageModule due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module toastr due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'toastr' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

As you can see from the page source below, there is a link to toastr, which if I click, it goes to the source file of javascript. I have tried alternating the order so jQuery loads first (doesn't help). What is causing these errors?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--STYLES-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/toastr/toastr.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/angular-toastr.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/bootstrap.3.1.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/importer.css">
    <!--STYLES END-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.SAILS_LOCALS = { _csrf: "null" };
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="HomepageModule" ng-controller="HomepageController" ng-cloak>
  //content of my page
  </body>

    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/toastr/toastr.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/compareTo.module.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/public/signup/SignupModule.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/private/dashboard/DashboardModule.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/public/homepage/HomepageModule.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/private/dashboard/DashboardController.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/public/homepage/HomepageController.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/public/signup/SignupController.js"></script>
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->
  </body>
</html>
```

HomePageModule:

```
angular.module('HomepageModule', ['toastr', 'compareTo']);
```

and then this is where it is used `HomepageController`:

```
angular.module('HomepageModule').controller('HomepageController', ['$scope', '$http', 'toastr', function($scope, $http, toastr){

    $scope.loginForm = {
        loading: false
    }

    $scope.submitLoginForm = function (){

    // Set the loading state (i.e. show loading spinner)
    $scope.loginForm.loading = true;

    // Submit request to Sails.
    $http.put('/login', {
      email: $scope.loginForm.email,
      password: $scope.loginForm.password
    })
    .then(function onSuccess (){
      // Refresh the page now that we've been logged in.
      window.location = '/';
    })
    .catch(function onError(sailsResponse) {

      // Handle known error type(s).
      // Invalid username / password combination.
      if (sailsResponse.status === 400 || 404) {

        toastr.error('Invalid email/password combination.', 'Error', {
          closeButton: true
        });
        return;
      }

                toastr.error('An unexpected error occurred, please try again.', 'Error', {
                    closeButton: true
                });
                return;

    })
    .finally(function eitherWay(){
      $scope.loginForm.loading = false;
    });
  };


}]);
```

Comment: Did you add the module as dependency? `angular.module('app', ['toastr'])`

Comment: @Michelem where would I add that?

Comment: Where you initialise your Angular app

Comment: Update your angular controller ...

Comment: @Michelem I have `angular.module('SignupModule', ['toastr', 'compareTo']);` in my `signupmodule.js` and the same in `homepagemodule.js`, with the correct module reference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr), which is a toastr JavaScript library and there [AngularJS-Toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster), which is an AngularJS toastr library.

You should be using the latter but it seems that you are using the former.

To use the latter in AngularJS try the following (as per the documentation):

```
angular.module('main', ['toaster', 'ngAnimate'])
    .controller('myController', function($scope, toaster) {
        $scope.pop = function(){
            toaster.pop('success', "title", "text");
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Include First angular js and then its dependencies always to avoid this kind of errors

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script> in head tag
<script src="/bower_components/toastr/toastr.js"></script> anywhere after head tag


angular.module('HomepageModule', ['toaster', 'ngAnimate'])
.controller('HomepageController', function($scope, toaster) {
    $scope.pop = function(){
        toaster.pop('success', "title", "text");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>  First
<script src="/bower_components/toastr/toastr.js"></script>    Second
```

Do not forget adding dependency
angular.module('app', ['toastr'])

Comment: I am afraid changing the order still hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

in my own case, i remembered to include my app.js script .